# Confidence interval from normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

Given $n=40$ (sample observations $y_i$) and sample mean $\overline{y}=195.47$, construct a $99\%$ confidence interval using the $G(\mu, 20)$ (normal) distribution and then interpret the interval.

My solution:

$$0.99=P\left( -2.58\le \frac{\overline{Y}-\mu}{\sqrt{20/40}} \le2.58 \right)$$
$$=P\left(\overline{Y}-1.7678\le \mu \le\overline{Y}+1.7678 \right)$$

Thus the confidence interval is $[193.7022,197.2378]$.

Interpretation: there is a 99% confidence that $\mu$ is in this interval.

I'd appreciate if someone would let me know if my construction is correct. Isn't my interval too narrow for this sample and mean? I know the concept should be pretty simple, but I got somewhat confused about some details from the text I read. Is my interpretation also correct?

Comment: Other than the fact that I don't know how you get $1.77$ from multiplying $2.58$ by $\sqrt{20/40}$ (it should be $1.82$), your confidence interval is correct. As a result of this small numerical error your interval is too narrow, but I don't know that that's what you were referring to. "There is a 99% confidence that $\mu$ is in this interval" is a pretty tautological interpretation of what a 99% confidence interval is and doesn't communicate any understanding of the concept.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for the correction. How would you interpret this? From the textbook I'm reading it appears to be that this means that the mean must be in this interval with 99% confidence.

Comment: what does "with 99% confidence" mean, though...?

Comment: Since it does not mean 99% probability, it just means confidence. To me, however, there is no difference between 99% probability and 99% confidence, but the text I have specifically emphasizes that 99% confidence is not the same as 99% probability. Quite confusing it is.

Comment: The difference is rooted at the difference between $\bar Y$ (a random variable) and $\bar y$ (its particular realization). So we can say there is a 0.99 probability that the random interval between $\bar Y -c$ and $\bar Y +c$ contains $\mu$ and this interval remains random until the sampling is completed. Once the specific realized value of $\bar y$ is plugged in, there is nothing random about the interval, and so the word probability has no place there.

Comment: The usual 'frequentist' interpretation of a 95% CI is that over the long run 95% CIs will cover their target parameters in 95% of situations in which they are used. Frequentist statisticians object to an interpretation that uses the word 'probability' in any one instance. That is the reason for using the word 'confidence' instead of 'probability'. // Bayesian statisticians begin with a prior distribution and base a 'probability interval' on the prior distribution and data. They do not object to the use of the word 'probability' for one particular instance.